# How to extract HTML element from a source file

Tags: php, html, extract

I need to replace a HTML section identified by a tag id in a source code, which is combination of HTML and PHP using PHP. In case it's pure HTML, DOM parser could be used; in case there is no DIV in DIV, I can imagine how to use preg_match. This is what I am trying to do - I have a code (loaded into a string) like:

```
<div>
  <img >
</div>

<? include(); ?>

<div id="mydiv">
   <div>
      <div>
        <img >
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and my task is to replace content of "mydiv" DIV with a new one e.g.

```
<div id="newdiv>
  some text
</div>
```

so the string will look like this after the change:

```
<div>
  <img >
</div>

<? include(); ?>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="newdiv>
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

I have already tried:

1) parsing the code using DOMdocument's `loadHTML` => it produces a lot of errors in case PHP code is included.

2) I played around a bit with regexes like `preg_match_all('/<div id="myid"([^<]*)<\/div>/', $src, $matches)`, which fails in case more child divs are included.

The best approach I have found so far is:

1) find `id="mydiv"` string

2) search for '<' and '>' chars and count them like '<'=1 and '>'=-1 (not exactly, but it gives the idea)

3) once I get `sum == 0` I should be on position of the closing tag, so I know, which portion string I should exchange

This is quite "heavy" solution, which can stop working in some cases, where the code is different (e.g. onpage PHP code contains the chars as well instead of just simple "include"). So I am looking so some better solution.

Comment: please share what you have tried until now, also a better explanation of the desired outcome would be useful...

Comment: I tried parsing the code using DOMdocument's loadHTML => it produces a lot of errors in case PHP code is included. I played around a bit with regexes like preg_match_all('/<div id="myid"([^<]*)<\/div>/', $src, $matches), which fails in case more child divs are included.

Comment: add all this to the original question by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36823546/edit) it...

Comment: I retracted my downvote...

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$file = 'filename.php';
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$array_one = explode( '<div id="mydiv">' , $content );
$my_div_content = explode("</div>" , $array_one[1] )[0];
```

Or use preg_match like you said:

```
preg_match('/<div id="mydiv"(.*?)<\/div>/s', $content, $matches)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid, it will work only in case there are no other DIVs in the root one ...  This is suggested in other posts here and I already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. First you need to use a function that will get the content of the file. Lets call the file homepage.php:

```
$homepageString = file_get_contents('homepage.php');
```

Now you have a string with all the content. The next thing you would do is use the preg_replace() function to take out the part of code that you want to take out:

```
$newHomepageString = preg_replace('/id="mydiv"/',"", $homepageString);
```

Now you overwrite the existing homepage.php file with the new source code:

```
file_put_contents("homepage.php", $newHomepageString);
```

Let me know if it worked for you! :)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to replace the string 'id="mydiv"' - I need to replace anything between <id="mydiv"> and related </div> closing tag with new content .... And the issue is, many e.g. <div> </div> tags can be there, so the root issue is how to find appropriate closing tag </div>. Sure, I can go through and count '<' and '>' chars, but I hoped a better solution exists.

Comment: @user3523426 I see. So why don't you create a php file that extracts information from a file (like a text file for instance) and places it in between the <div id='mydiv'>...</div> tag? That way, whenever you want to update the content, all you have to do is change the information inside the text file. Is that appropriate for you?

Comment: That's what I would like to do - my question was about how to find correct <div></div> pair in case there are more child div objects inside the main one - so in the situation, where simple looking for next </div> is not sufficient. I hoped DOMdocument parsers has some "magic" parameter for parsing included PHP code or so. It looks like I have to parse the code manually.